# Beginning of JSON Work - Getting Values

Tags: java, json, double

I'm not too experienced-or experienced at all for that matter with JSON. I'm using the official JSON-in-Java package, and it somewhat works... not really.

With JSON like this:

```
{
    "versions": [
        {
            "name": "1.4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comes this:

> JSONObject["versions.name"] not found.

I've tried the keys "versions.name," "name," etc.

This is the code I use (I know it works...):

```
TheJSONObject.getDouble("key");
```

Comment: What's the "official" JSON-in-Java package?

Comment: Your JSON describes an object with a "versions" property. The value of "versions" is an array. That array has a single object with a "name" property. The value of that "name" property is the String "1.4". So you're looking for something along the lines of theJSONObject.get("versions").get(0).get("name")